# Asciidoc - Formatted Text in Admonition - Caution, Important, Note, Warning

Tags: asciidoc, gitlab-wiki

I tried

```
IMPORTANT: * [ ] A checkbox
```

but the text after `IMPORTANT:` is not rendered as checkbox. Instead it is printed as is.

How can I convince the asciidoc processor (gitlab wiki) to render the text  properly and display a checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the detailed block notation for [Admonitions](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/syntax-quick-reference/#admonitions).

```
[IMPORTANT]
====
* [ ] A Checkbox
====
```